# Configuring OCSP stapling in NGINX

Tags: nginx, tls, ocsp

Should I concatenate all certificates(server + intermediates + root) or just(server + intermediates) for **`ssl_trusted_certificate`** directive in **NGINX**.

Comment: You should show what you did up until now to solve this on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following setting

```
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/root_CA_cert_plus_intermediates;
```

to configure OCSP Stapling (the server certificate should not be concatenated here), but you should use `ssl_certificate`, where the server certificate is provided together with all intermediate certificates:

```
ssl_certificate /path/to/signed_cert_plus_intermediates;
```

On the other side one should don't include the `root_CA_cert` here.

Comment: So for OCSP intermediate certs + root only.
I know about other things.

Comment: Ah, and I forgot, what order for `ssl_trusted_certificate` root + intermediate or intermediate + root. Please edit your answer when you can.